# If Mayu had no contact with the outside world, how did she contact people in the outside world?

Tags: wixoss

When Mayu created the selector LRIGs, she was being raised in solitude with no access to the outside world or other humans, apart from maids who made sure her simple needs were met. They did not speak to Mayu whilst in her solitude.

Knowing this, how was it possible for the selector LRIGs to leave Mayu's confined space and enter into the outside world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication is that, upon her death, Mayu's ghost was what made her imagined Eternal Girl system into a reality. (In the flashbacks, we see her orchestrating it from her room with the implication that at that point it was all in her warped imagination.)